# Обновление страницы после нажатие submit

Tags: php, ajax, submit

как отключить обновление страницы после отправки формы?
p.s.: код не мой.

```
        if (!empty($uname)){
        echo "<br><b>Поручено:</b><br>".$uname;
        echo "<br><br><form action=\"";
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        echo "\" method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='button3' value='Cбросить'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Назначить:";
        echo "<form action=\"";
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        echo "\" method='post'>";
        echo "<select name='stat'>";
        echo "<option value=''></option>";
        foreach ($specs as $spec){
            if($spec['id']==28) { ""; } else {
                echo "<option value='".$spec['stat']."'>".$spec['name']."</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select><br/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id'].">";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='button1' value='Назначить'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

ну вот ставил сюда теперь формы не отправляются

```
if (!empty($uname)){
        echo "<br><b>Поручено:</b><br>".$uname;
        echo "<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
        echo "<form target='responseframe' action=\"";
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        echo "\" method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='button3' value='Cбросить'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Назначить:";
        echo "<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
        echo "<form target='responseframe' action=\"";
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        echo "\" method='post'>";
        echo "<select name='stat'>";
        echo "<option value=''></option>";
        foreach ($specs as $spec){
            if($spec['id']==28) { ""; } else {
                echo "<option value='".$spec['stat']."'>".$spec['name']."</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select><br/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id'].">";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='button1' value='Назначить'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

сама страница

```
<?php
$ctrl=0;
$pg=1;
include('inc/contr_menu.php');

$query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `control` WHERE `ctrl`='0' AND `date` LIKE '$year-$month%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$count = $result->fetch_assoc();
$cnt=$count['count'];
echo "<div width=50% style='float:right;padding-right: 35%; padding-left: 2%;'><h1>Поручения. За ".monthTXT($month)." всего ".$cnt."</h1></div>";

include('inc/search.php');

//*********************************base table **********************************/
$shq=$sh.'control/admin/js/';
$shn=$sh.'control/admin/inc/';
?>
<div id='answer'>
<script src="<?=$shq;?>jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=$shq;?>jmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img src="<?=$shq;?>load.gif" style="display:none">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".refa").live("click", function() { var id = $(this).attr("id"); var string = 'id='+ id ; $("#otvet"+ id).html("<img src=<?=$shq;?>load.gif>"); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "<?=$shn;?>ajax_hide.php", data: string, cache: false, success: function(data) { $("#otvet"+ id).html(data); }, error: function(obj, err) { $("#otvet"+ id).text("Ошибка..."); } }); return false; });
$(".refshow").live("click", function() { var id = $(this).attr("id"); var string = 'id='+ id ; $("#otvet"+ id).html("<img src=<?=$shq;?>load.gif>"); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "<?=$shn;?>ajax_show.php", data: string, cache: false, success: function(data) { $("#otvet"+ id).html(data); }, error: function(obj, err) { $("#otvet"+ id).text("Ошибка..."); } }); return false; });
});
</script>


<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr><th width='5%'><a href='index.php?sort=desc'>№</a><br><a href='index.php?sort=asc'>ID</a></th><th width='40%'>Поручение</th>
<th width='15%'>Отдел<br>Поручено<br>Исполнитель</th>
<th><a title="По дате выполнения.По убыванию" href='index.php?sort=date'>Срок</a><br><br><a title="По дате создания" href='index.php?sort=now'>Дата</a></th>
<th>Испол<br>-нено</th><th width='20%'>Ответ</th><th width='10%'>Комментарий службы контроля</th><th width='20%'>Документы</th></tr>
<?php
$i = 1;
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $id_contr = $row['id'];
    $stat=$row['stat'];
    $day_performed2=$row['day_performed2'];
        $dates = explode('-',$row['date']);
    $date1 = $dates[2]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[0];
    $spec_id=$row['spec_id'];
    //$date1 = $dates[2]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[0];
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d');
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date2);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $days_with_symbol = $interval->format('%R%a');
    $days = $interval->format('%a');

    //Вычисляем цвет, чем больше просрочка тем краснее цвет.
    //Если просрочка слишком большая и голубой и зеленый цвет в
    //диапазоне RGB не ушли на отрицательное число приравниваем
    //$gb = 0; (минимальный цвет для Green и Blue)
    $gb = 210 - 10*$days;
    if ($gb<0){
        $gb = 0;
    }
    $color = rgbtohex(255,$gb,$gb);

    //Чем меньше дней осталось до конца исполнения поручения, 
    //тем желтее делаем цвет поручения
    $b = 50*$days;
    if ($b>255){
        $b = 255;
    }
    $g = 170 + 20*$days;
    if ($g>255){
        $g = 255;
    }
    $color2 = rgbtohex(255,$g,$b);

    $flag = 0;
    if (strlen($row['answer'])>400){
        $answer = mb_substr($row['answer'],0,400);
        $answer = $answer."...";
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else{
        $answer = nl2br($row['answer']);
    }
    if ($row['ctrl']){
        $ctrl = "Да";
    }
    else{
        $ctrl = "Нет";
    }

    $specs =array();
    $query="SELECT name,stat FROM users WHERE `id_dep`='".$row['dep_id']."'";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($spec = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        $specs[] = $spec;
    }

    //Начинаем рисовать таблицу
    echo "<tr><td  valign='top'>$i<br>$id_contr</td>";

    //Если поручение было с пунктами (item_descr не пустой),
    //тогда вставляем описание поручения (item_descr) и пункт поручения.
    //Иначе выводим только пункт (получается поручение из одного пункта)
    if (!empty($row['item_descr'])){
        echo "<td valign='top' >".$row['item_descr']."<br/>".$row['descr'];
    }
    else {
        echo "<td valign='top' >".$row['descr'];
    }
    echo "<br/><a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id'].$mon."\">Редактировать</a></td>";
    echo "<td  valign='top'><b>Отдел:</b><br>".$row['dep_name']."<br>";
    if($stat==0) {  ""; }
elseif($stat>0){
    $query="SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `stat`='".$stat."'";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        $rod = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $uname=$rod['name']; }
    //Если ответственный специалист за поручение не назначен, то даем 
    //возможность выбрать специалиста из ответственного Отдела
        if (!empty($uname)){
            echo "<br><b>Поручено:</b><br>".$uname;
            echo "<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
            echo "<form target='responseframe' action=\"";
            $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            echo "\" method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='button3' value='Cбросить'>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<br>Назначить:";
            echo "<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
            echo "<form target='responseframe' action=\"";
            $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            echo "\" method='post'>";
            echo "<select name='stat'>";
            echo "<option value=''></option>";
            foreach ($specs as $spec){
                if($spec['id']==28) { ""; } else {
                    echo "<option value='".$spec['stat']."'>".$spec['name']."</option>";
                }
            }
            echo "</select><br/>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id'].">";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='button1' value='Назначить'>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/control/admin/inc/script.php');

    if ($row['ctrl']){
        echo "<td valign='top' bgcolor='#CCC' width='100'>".$rdate."<br>";
        if ($row['performed']){
            echo "Просрочено на ".$row['performed'];
            if ($row['performed']==1 || (($row['performed'] % 10)==1 and $row['performed']!=11)){
                echo " день";
            }
            elseif($row['performed']<5 || (($row['performed'] % 10)<5 and $row['performed']>15 )){
                echo " дня";
            }
            else{
                echo " дней";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "В срок";
        }
        echo "<br>Дата создания:<br> <b>".$day_performed2."</b></td>";
    }
    else{
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/control/admin/inc/date.php');
    }

    //Рисуем возможность изменять Исполнение путем выбора из выпадающего списка
    echo "<td  valign='top'>";
    if ($row['ctrl']){
        echo "Да";
    }
    else {

    if($row['ctrl']==1) { $imgst='lg1'; $tit2='title="Выполнено"'; $clsref='class="refa"'; }
else { $imgst='lg2'; $tit2='title="Не выполнено"'; $clsref='class="refshow"';  }
echo '<span id=otvet'.$row['id'].'>';
echo     '<a '.$tit2.' id="'.$row['id'].'" '.$clsref.'><img class="'.$imgst.'" src="'.$sh.'img/pic.png"></a></span></td>';

        }

    echo "<td width='600' valign='top'>".$answer."<a href=\"/control/admin/detail.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Подробнее</a><br/></td>";
    echo "<td valign='top'>".$row['comment']."<br/><a href='add_comment.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Добавить </a></td>";

    $refds='<a href="/control/admin/files.php?id_cont='.$id_contr.'"><b>Добавить файлы</b></a>';
    echo "<td valign='top'>".$refds."<br>Файлы:<br>";

$query="SELECT file,id FROM `files` WHERE id_cont='".$id_contr."' ";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        $d=1;
        while ($fil = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        $dir='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/files/';
    $files=$fil['file'];
    echo $d.' - <a href="'.$dir.$files.'"><span class="txt1"">Скачать</span></a><br>';
    $d++;
    }

    echo "</td></tr>";


unset($stat); unset($uname);

    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";


?>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Использовать AJAX (либо для других задач - JS)

Comment: 1. Мешанина html в php плохая практика. 2. Либо AJAX либо header("Location:")

Answer (score 1):

Отправляйте данные из формы при помощи [нативного js](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) или [библиотеки jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Приведу пример с использованием jquery:

```
<form action="action_name" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input name="my_data1" type="text" />
    <input name="my_data2" type="text" />
    <input name="my_data3" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function() { // Отслеживаем событие отправки 
        var string = $(this).serialize(); // Сериализуем все данные формы чтоб не пришлось явно указывать каждое её поле
        var method = $(this).attr('method'); // Достаем метод отправки
        var action = $(this).attr('action'); // И урл экшена
        $.ajax({ // Отправляем данные при помощи метода библиотеки 
            type: method,
            url: action,
            data: string,
            dataType: "json", // Указываем в каком формате ожидаем получить ответ
            success: function(request) { // Описываем сценарий при получении ответа
                alert(request.message);
            },
            error: function() { // Описываем сценарий при ошибке отправки
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

HTML

```html
<form target='responseframe'>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank'></iframe>
```

PHP

```
echo "<iframe name='responseframe' src='about:blank' style='display:none;'></iframe>";
echo "<form target='responseframe' action=\"";
...
```

Comment: Наманый костыль)

Comment: и как это вписать? через echo?

Comment: теперь у меня формы не отправляются

Comment: Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код :)

Comment: уверяю вас скопировал все как надо

Comment: может не в той строке?

Comment: хм, добавьте в Ваш вопрос новый вариант кода - ссылка "править" под вопросом

Comment: @АнатолийКуприянов а как Вы узнали, что форма не отправляется?

Comment: когда я нажимаю сбросить\назначить просто ничего не происхождит

Comment: страница просто становится белой

Comment: а можно в пхп ))

Comment: а Вы не могли бы скопировать  из баузера в вопрос html, который получается?

Comment: @Igor формы отправляются после обновление страницы

Comment: @АнатолийКуприянов "формы отправляются после обновление страницы" - это как? я имел в виду html из браузера - без PHP