# Создать POST-запрос без перенаправления

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно создать post-запрос в iframe html-страницы, но после запроса пользователь автоматически перенаправляется на страницу обработчика запроса.

Я хочу создать запрос без редиректа

```
<div class="control-group">

<form id="main-mailing-list" action="https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXX/sendMessage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

  <input type="hidden" name="chat_id" value="-44947">
  <input tabindex="0" autocomplete="email" id="emailfield" data-validation="email" class="required email" name="text" type="email" placeholder="Your email address">

  <button id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button><br><br>
  <span id="thanks"></span>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Тогда используйте `Ajax`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать пустой `iframe`: `<iframe name="empty" src="_blank"></iframe>`

А у формы добавьте атрибут `target="empty"`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает :). Добавил еще iframe размер в 1 пиксель